# Prevent additional top level categories but allow more children

Tags: posts, categories, admin

Is it possible to prevent additional parent categories being added to posts but allow children categories to be added to predefined parent categories?

For e.g.;

**Food & Drink**

-- Mexican

-- Italian

-- American

**Sports**

-- Tennis

-- Football

Is it possible to only allow additional categories to be added under either Food & Drink or Sports?